# Use angular expression within the same object with ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, expression

just wondering if anyone knows how i can get an angular expression from within the ng-repeat, in the same object. eg

```
    <!..This is the abgpankit..>
    <div ng-repeat="equip in portal[0].equipment[0].sub" id="{{equip.id}}" class="displaydiv">
        <div class="contentimg">
            <h3>{{equip.item}}</h3>
        </div>
            <a ng-repeat="x in equip.links" href="#pdfdiv" onclick ="return iframeSrc("{{x.links}}");">
            <li>{{x.desc}}</li></a>
        <div class="information">
            <p>{{equip.info}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Items in Kit</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="icons">
                        <a href="#panharness" class="panharnessicon">
                        <div class="iconimg">
                        <h2>Pan Harness</h2></div></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="icons">
                        <a href="#displaymodule" class="displaymodicon">
                        <div class="iconimg">
                        <h2>Display Module</h2></div></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="icons">
                        <a href="#halo" class="haloicon">
                        <div class="iconimg">
                        <h2>Halo</h2></div></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="icons">
                        <a href="#edm" class="edmicon">
                        <div class="iconimg">
                        <h2>EDM</h2></div></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="icons">
                        <a href="#dm" class="dmicon">
                        <div class="iconimg">
                        <h2>DM</h2></div></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="icons">
                        <a href="#sft" class="sfticon">
                        <div class="iconimg">
                        <h2>SFT</h2></div></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sorry just changed it to the actually code from the site. I believe i have the syntax right, i just though there might be some limitation using an expression in the same object the ng-repeat is defined in.
Once i sort this out i can move further down and fix things up.

Cheers,
Mitchell

Comment: What do you mean by *how i can get an angular expression from within the ng-repeat*? What you wrote should work.

Comment: no it does not. Anything within that <div> tag doesnt seem to work. If i do <div ng-repeat"item in equipment><a id={{item}}></a></div> it works. But i can't seem to reference the item within the same object where ngrepeat is defined

Comment: Provide a plunker or fiddle with problem statement please

Comment: there you missed `}` closing parenthesis at the end, it should be `id="{{item}}"`

Comment: sorry that was me doing an example i have the appropriate quotes....  <div ng-repeat="equip in portal[0].equipment[0].sub" id="{{equip.id}}" class="displaydiv">
   <div class="contentimg">
    <h3>{{equip.item}}</h3>
   </div>